# Resources won't load with the second url pattern in J2EE

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, resources, url-pattern, eclipse-jee

I'm having a *strange* problem, i have a servlet that is mapped to **/home** and **/home/next** with the web annotation as follows:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns= {"/home", "/home/next"})
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

and it's doGet method send an index.jsp that has the following:

```
<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="logo">
</body>
```

and the files hierarchy is as follows:

- src/main/

  - java/

    - IndexServlet.java
  - webapp/

    - WEB-INF/

      - index.jsp
    - resources/

      - logo.png

And here is the problem, when i access

> localhost:8080/_08/home      *(_08 is the projects name)*

Everything is as to be expected, it works fine.
However, if i were to access

> localhost:8080/_08/home/next

I get the expected jsp but the image won't load, i get the broken image icon.

I dont understand why it happens, i tried adding a url pattern like this:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns= {"/home", "/home/next", "/foo", "/foo/bar"})
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
```

and i get the same result, the **/foo** work, but **/foo/bar** doesn't, it also won't load the image.
I'm using Tomcat v10.0 and Eclipse JEE IDE.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague gave me the answer, it turns out i already stumbled upon it but not in this context.
Not adding a  **'/'** at the beginning of your href will look for the path relative to where it is. For example in the *localhost:8080/_08/home* it looked for the image in *localhost:8080/_08/* which explains why it worked, because that's where the image is, it's in /_08/resources/logo.png (the WebApp is _08), but when i go to *localhost:8080/_08/home/next* it look for it in *localhost:8080/_08/home/*.
Adding a **'/'** at the beginning specifies that the path is from the root of the WebApp, so making editing the jsp to this solves the problem:

```
<img src="/_08/resources/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

However that is an app based solution, and what should be used is:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/logo.png" alt="logo">
```

Which returns the *root dir* for your WebApp.
Same problem will occur with anchor links, same solution tho.